# Show that the series $∑_{m=1}^{∞}(r^{-m}/(2^{m}-1))$ is convergente for some positive integer $r>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The **Erdős-Borwein Constant** can be found in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erdos-BorweinConstant.html

My question is : Show that the series $$∑_{m=1}^{∞}r^{-m}/(2^{m}-1)$$ is convergente for some positive integer $r>0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $r \geq 1$
$$\frac{r^{-m}}{2^{m}-1}=\frac{1}{r^{m}(2^{m}-1)} \leq \frac{1}{(2^{m}-1)} \leq \frac{1}{(2^{m}-2^{m-1})}= \frac{1}{2^{m-1}}  $$

Comment: Your inequality is wrong.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I corrected it yesterday thanks.